# Python dictionary iteratively expanded into lists

Tags: python, list, dictionary, list-comprehension

I have the following Python dictionary:

```
 b = {'SP:1': 1.0,
      'SP:2': 2.0,
      'SP:3': 3.0,
      'SP:4': 4.0,
      'SP:5': 5.0,
      'SP:6': 6.0,
      'SP:7': 40.0,
      'SP:8': 7.0,
      'SP:9': 8.0}
```

I want to take this list and iterate over it to create 9 `lists`, each successive list being a superset of its predecessor. So:

```
 [1.0]
 [1.0,2.0]
 [1.0,2.0,3.0]
 [1.0,2.0,3.0,4.0]
 ...
 [1.0,2.0,3.0,4.0,5.0,6.0,40.0,7.0,8.0]
```

There is probably a really easy way of doing this with a list comprehension, but I cant work it out!

Comment: Dicts with consecutive integer keys should usually be lists in the first place.

Comment: What have you tried yourself? show us the code please...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do the following:

```
>>> vals = [v for k, v in sorted(b.items())]
# or shorter, but less explicit:
# vals = [b[k] for k in sorted(b)]
>>> [vals[:i+1] for i in range(len(vals))]
[[1.0],
 [1.0, 2.0],
 [1.0, 2.0, 3.0],
 [1.0, 2.0, 3.0, 4.0],
 [1.0, 2.0, 3.0, 4.0, 5.0],
 [1.0, 2.0, 3.0, 4.0, 5.0, 6.0],
 [1.0, 2.0, 3.0, 4.0, 5.0, 6.0, 40.0],
 [1.0, 2.0, 3.0, 4.0, 5.0, 6.0, 40.0, 7.0],
 [1.0, 2.0, 3.0, 4.0, 5.0, 6.0, 40.0, 7.0, 8.0]]
```

The first comprehension gives you the values sorted by key as the initial `dict` is inherently unordered. The second gives you all of the desired slices of that list of values.

Answer (score 3):

Dictionaries are not meant to be used in this form, and should never considered to be ordered. However, since the keys are basically indicies, we can use them like that:

```
[[b['SP:'+str(j+1)] for j in range(i+1)] for i in range(len(b))]
```

Comment: I think there is a small typo here - this works: `[[b['SP:'+str(j+1)] for j in range(i+1)] for i in range(len(b))]`